# web3 1.0 getPastLogs with geth --syncmode light

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js

When I use geth client in sync mode "**light** " getPastLogs returns data with no assignment to blockNumber:

```
[ { address: '0x4092678e4E78230F46A1534C0fbc8fA39780892B',
    topics:
     [ '0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef',
       '0x00000000000000000000000068eff2d6b47b5bc6966c199f1d3a9c4c8ae04dd5',
       '0x00000000000000000000000046705dfff24256421a05d056c29e81bdc09723b8' ],
    data: '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000039e8523cda6344fe0000',
    blockNumber: 0,
    transactionHash: '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
    transactionIndex: 0,
    blockHash: '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
    logIndex: 0,
    removed: false,
    id: 'log_247b1779' } ]
```

Are there any way to get info about blockNumber using this syncmode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: had to update geth from 1.7 to 1.8